# Twig CamelCase Filter in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

So I'm pretty new to Symfony2 and I'm trying to use the `camelize` filter in a twig template. However when I request the page I get an error saying that the filter doesn't exist:

> The filter "camelize" does not exist in ::base.html.twig

Here's the line from my template file:

> {{ 'hello world' | camelize }}

The filter is listed on Twig's [quick reference page](https://github.com/vito/chyrp/wiki/Twig-Reference).

I'm confused, doesn't Symfony2 support all of twig's filters? There seem to be quite a few missing, why? And if it doesn't support them, then is there any way to add the missing ones in?

Thanks in advance!

**edit** Ok, so it turns out I'm retarded and I need to remember to check that I've actually got the right git project. No wonder I was confused. Thanks replies!

Comment: I don't know where you got that reference page, but that doesn't seem to be the correct Twig.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your link points to a **fork** on GitHub, meaning a modified copy of the original project. The original project is https://github.com/fabpot/Twig.

There is no `camelize` filter in Twig. Built-in filters are [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html). You can write your own camilize filter (it's easy, actually...) following this tutorial: [How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

**EDIT**: just for fun, you can write something like:

```php
class MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'camelize' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'camelizeFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function camelizeFilter($value)
    {
        if(!is_string($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        $chunks    = explode(' ', $value);
        $ucfirsted = array_map(function($s) { return ucfirst($s); }, $chunks);

        return implode('', $ucfirsted);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Note that this is a quick and dirty filter! Take a look at the built-in filters to learn best practice!

Comment: Doctrine's `Inflector` class has the `camelize` method, you could use that instead of writing your own, however it's identical to what you wrote anyway.

Comment: You can use `ucfirst` directly here in the `array_map` as it has the same signature. `array_map('ucfirst', $chunks);`

Answer (score 12):

Symfony 2 has title filter for camel case use

```
{{ entity.yourstring | title }}
```

to camel case your string

Comment: The `title` filter returns a PascalCase string, not a camelCase string.

Answer (score 3):

The filter you're looking for is named "title": http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/title.html

Answer (score 1):

In case someone doesn't want to write a php funtion or filter for a solution, which is recommended if you're trying to use the camelizer in a lot of places during your programming, here is a solution using only Twig step by step cutting words and updating them:
in this case, I will make a snake case into a camel case, which will hopefully cover all possible scenarios:

```
    {% set snakeVariable = "snake_to_camel_case" %}

{# first we remove all the underscores _ from snakeVariable #}
{% set variable = snakeVariable|replace({'_': ' '}) %} {# output : "snake to camel case" #}
{% set words = variable|split(' ') %}
{# output :
array:3 [▼
0 => "snake"
1 => "to"
2 => "camel"
3 => "case"
] #}

{# now we take the first word seperately #}
{% set firstWord = words|first %} {# output : snake }


{# here we take the rest of the words cutting out the first word with slice(1) #}
{# join the array words using  join(' ') #}
{# uppercase every first letter of the words |title #}
{# remove whitespace between the words replace({' ': ''} #}
{% set restWords = words|slice(1)|join(' ')|title|replace({' ': ''})  %} {# output: ToCamelCase }


{# combine the whole variable back to one  " snake ~ ToCamelCase #}
{% set allWords = firstWord ~ restWords %}
All words: {{ allWords }} {# output: snakeToCamelCase #}
```

I tried explaining the filters and functions using in-code comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution by default in Craft CMS 3

Craft 3 now has a `|camel` filter for twig

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#camel

```
{{ 'foo bar'|camel }}
{# Output: fooBar #}
```